# Open link in a named tab and activate it if already opened?

Tags: javascript, html

Now I have links:

```
<a href="123.html" target="view1">123</a>
<a href="345.html" target="view2">345</a>
```

If a link is clicked for the first time, then new tab is created. That's Ok.

When I click the clicked link second time, the opened tab refreshes. That's Ok, but first time I click, the tab is created and brought to front, and second time I should search the tab I need, because it is not popping up like it does first time.

So, I need to find and bring to front already opened window/tab. Is it possible?

Comment: I suppose this behavior is up to the browser settings. For example, Firefox 22 has the 'When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately' checkbox in the settings dialog. I don't think that there is the easy way to override these settings.

Comment: Do you mean several tabs within the same html page similar to the tabs [summary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1571000/e-l?tab=summary), [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1571000/e-l?tab=answers) in the user page or do you really mean, that if you click on a link the browser should open an new instances (new window) as a tab?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: I mean any several tabs with opened sites, as usual in browsers

Comment: If it is not programming related but how a certain application (like a browser) has to be configured it belongs to superuser.